# Take picture without saving it

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to call the android's native camera and don't save it in the storage, because I save it myself after processing image. It works almost for all devices, except Motorola XT1032 (Android 5.1, API 22). So is there a way to tell the camera not to save the picture?
Here is how I call the camera intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM) + File.separator + "image_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(intent, 1001);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the request code variable:

```
private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 1;
```

Open the camera:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
```

and in case you want to show it to the user:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
case REQUEST_CAMERA:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    // successfully captured the image

                    Bitmap mBitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                    if (mBitmap != null) {
                      imageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
                    }
}


}
```